# Is it possible to setup PPTP VPN connection on AWS EC2?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, vpn, pptp

Is it possible to connect to AWS EC2 machine via my local PC using PPTP VPN connection?
Both machines are running Windows Server 201x, and I've enabled predefined routing windows firewall inbound rules for both of them.
I've also forwarded port 1723 to my local PC and enabled all TCP/UDP connections from my local PC, what am I doing wrong? Do I have to switch something up in my security group settings and/or somehow allow GRE 47?

P.S - I know that PPTP is highly unsafe and such, but I'm not going to use it to transfer any sensitive info.

Comment: I've never heard of AWS offering a PPTP VPN as a service. IPSec, yes, but it'll cost you about $20 a month plus traffic. Opening up your VPC to your public IP might be a cheaper, easier way. You can also consider using a Client VPN, which if you're careful can be cheap if you disassociate the subnet associations when you're not using it - can be done using CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to start is open *all traffic* from your IP in the Security Group. That way you can test if it works without AWS network firewall (ie Security Group) stepping in.